# Upload image to salesforce s-drive using the salesforce android sdk

Tags: android, amazon-s3, salesforce

I cannot find documentation on how to use Salesforce Mobile SDK (Android) to upload an image. I am using the SDriveTools app which integrates Amazon S3 as a related list.

can someone provide an example? The documentation isn't very clear